# Can we directly use the protobuf in spring-kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, spring-kafka

I want to create the a spring boot application with Kafka where producer and consumer both will use the protobuf only.

I tried with confluent deserializer but while trying that I'm getting so many parsing errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use `protobuf-java` to create a `byte[]` that can be sent with `ByteArraySerializer` or get `Message` from byte array returned from `ByteArrayDeserializer`. Spring Boot is not necessary.

Otherwise, you need to write your own Serializer and Deserializer implementations for using Protobuf Message class, or POJOs.

You'll have the same "parser issues", regardless of what framework is used, if your protobuf schema definition is invalid, as Confluent simply wraps that same library.